# Javascript package or plugin to create network diagrams with IPs

Tags: javascript, networking, vue.js

Is there a plugin or a package where I can create visual network diagrams like in cisco packet tracer, so that our technicians can request their network schedule per customer.

I have already seen protovis and infovis go by, but it can not do what I really want.

What I actually want is something like the picture.

If you need more information, let me know and if the question is wrong, do not hesitate to correct me.

thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Maybe dot/graphviz is useful, there is a c# wrapper  on github https://github.com/vfrz/DotNetGraph

Comment: @MikNiller I'm using vuejs, is there a javascript ecuivalent package?

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._" Perhaps your question is better asked on something like [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: @RonMaupin Thank you for pointing out my mistake, I will move my question to the right website

Answer (score 1):

Please look up https://gojs.net/latest/samples/index.html 
- these are javascript based
- Individual classes are also available (which you can customize for a new visualization)
- It can be installed via npm, and, if you don't like it, can be easily removed from the system.
I hope this helps.
regards
SS